# i have problem with the package "awesome_dialog" in flutter

Tags: flutter

i try use the package "awesome_dialog" which is available here : https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_dialog

But it doesn't work correctly :(

Here is the code i use :

```
AwesomeDialog(
                          context: context,
                          useRootNavigator: true,
                          animType: AnimType.TOPSLIDE,
                          dialogType: DialogType.WARNING,
                          tittle: "pas de titre",
                          desc: "Vous ne pouvez pas sélectionner plus de 5 numéros !!!",
                          btnOkOnPress: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                        ).show();
```

The result is it goes to the previous page… Normally when i click on OK it would be keep on the same page. And if i delete the line useRootNavigator i have a big error :

"The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.

To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method."

Before using this package my code was :

```
showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context){
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: Text("Vous ne pouvez pas sélectionner plus de 5 numéros !!!"),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                                actions: <Widget>[
                                  FlatButton(
                                    child: new Text("OK"),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            }
                        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use navigator, it will taken care by package it self.

```
btnOkOnPress: () {
    //      Navigator.pop(context);  // commented line
},
```

You will find out this in [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_dialog) part of package.

Comment: Thanks :) Can you say you what do exactly Navigator.pop(context); ??? Because it goes to previous page for me when i test

Comment: Navigator.pop(context);  use to navigate back to previous screen but in this package they call Navigator.pop(context);  inside so we don't have to call ourselves.